# call soundtouch code in my c code, the programe crashed

Tags: android, c++, soundtouch

I want to call C++ method in pure c code, and I follow a article. The bridge is below:

```
extern "C" {
    void setSampleRateForC(SoundTouch *p, uint rate) {p->setSampleRate(rate);}
    void setChannelsForC(SoundTouch *p, uint channels){ p->setChannels(channels);}
    void setTempoChangeForC(SoundTouch *p, float tempo ){ p->setTempoChange(tempo);}
    void setRateChangeForC(SoundTouch *p, float rate ){ p->setRateChange(rate);}
    void setPitchSemiTonesForC(SoundTouch *p, float pitch) {p->setPitchSemiTones(pitch);}
    BOOL setSettingForC(SoundTouch *p, int settingId, int value) { return p->setSetting(settingId, value);}

    void setRateForC(SoundTouch *p, uint rate) {p->setRate(rate);}
    void setTempoForC(SoundTouch *p, float tempo ){ p->setTempo(tempo);}
    void setPitchForC(SoundTouch *p, float pitch) {p->setPitch(pitch);}

    void putSamplesForC(SoundTouch *p,
            const SAMPLETYPE *samples,  ///< Pointer to sample buffer.
            uint numSamples                         ///< Number of samples in buffer. Notice
                                                    ///< that in case of stereo-sound a single sample
                                                    ///< contains data for both channels.
            ){ p->putSamples(samples, numSamples);}

    uint receiveSamplesForC(SoundTouch *p, SAMPLETYPE *output, ///< Buffer where to copy output samples.
                                uint maxSamples                 ///< How many samples to receive at max.
                                ) {
                return p->receiveSamples(output, maxSamples);
    }

    SoundTouch *getInstance(){
       return getInstance();
    }
```

but when i call the getIntance() in my c code, and the program is crashed. so  I want to know, what's wrong with the code.

```
 LOGE("%s init SoundTouch begin", THIS_FILE);
    pSoundTouch = soundtouch::getInstance();
    LOGE("%s", THIS_FILE);
```

But only find init SoundTouch begin in logcat, and the next log is not appear in the logcat. please help me. thank you.
and the getInstance() is:

```
SoundTouch *SoundTouch::getInstance(){
    return new SoundTouch();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK,I have solved it by write a wrapper:

```
// uses C calling convention
#include "SoundTouch.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void* SoundTouch_Create(){
    return new SoundTouch();
}

void SoundTouch_Destroy( void* thisC )
{
    delete static_cast<SoundTouch*>(thisC);
}

void setSampleRateForC(void* thisC , uint rate) {static_cast<SoundTouch*>(thisC)->setSampleRate(rate);}
    void setChannelsForC(void* thisC, uint channels){ static_cast<SoundTouch*>(thisC)->setChannels(channels);}
    void setTempoChangeForC(void* thisC, float tempo ){ static_cast<SoundTouch*>(thisC)->setTempoChange(tempo);}
    void setRateChangeForC(void* thisC, float rate ){ static_cast<SoundTouch*>(thisC)->setRateChange(rate);}
    void setPitchSemiTonesForC(void* thisC, float pitch) {static_cast<SoundTouch*>(thisC)->setPitchSemiTones(pitch);}
    BOOL setSettingForC(void* thisC, int settingId, int value) { return static_cast<SoundTouch*>(thisC)->setSetting(settingId, value);}

    void setRateForC(void* thisC, uint rate) {static_cast<SoundTouch*>(thisC)->setRate(rate);}
    void setTempoForC(void* thisC, float tempo ){ static_cast<SoundTouch*>(thisC)->setTempo(tempo);}
    void setPitchForC(void* thisC, float pitch) {static_cast<SoundTouch*>(thisC)->setPitch(pitch);}

    void putSamplesForC(void* thisC,
            const SAMPLETYPE *samples,  ///< Pointer to sample buffer.
            uint numSamples                         ///< Number of samples in buffer. Notice
                                                    ///< that in case of stereo-sound a single sample
                                                    ///< contains data for both channels.
            ){ 
                static_cast<SoundTouch*>(thisC)->putSamples(samples, numSamples);
             }

    uint receiveSamplesForC(void* thisC, SAMPLETYPE *output, ///< Buffer where to copy output samples.
                                uint maxSamples                 ///< How many samples to receive at max.
                                ) 
    {
        return static_cast<SoundTouch*>(thisC)->receiveSamples(output, maxSamples);
    }

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```